# Is the use of conversion operator forbidden for the lhs of user-defined operator= for user-defined types? If so, what part of the standars forbids it?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, assignment-operator, conversion-operator

Take a simple class wrapping an `int`,

```cpp
struct Foo {
    int x;
} f;
```

and a class that holds a `Foo` and that can be converted to it,

```cpp
struct Bar {
    Foo f;
    operator Foo&() {
        return f;
    }
    operator Foo const&() const {
        return f;
    }
    Bar& operator=(Bar const&) = default;
} b;
```

What part of the standard, if any, makes this invalid

```cpp
b = f;
```

instead of being equivalent to this?

```cpp
static_cast<Foo&>(b) = f;
```

(I'm not saying it should, nor that it would be normal, expected or anything like that.)

[Here](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.oper#5) I read that

> For the built-in assignment operators, conversions of the left operand are restricted as follows:
>
> - [...]
> - no user-defined conversions are applied to the left operand to achieve a type match with the left-most parameter of a built-in candidate.
>
> For all other operators, no such restrictions apply.

So am I misunderstanding the meaning of "built-in assignment operator" and the `=` in `b = f` is the built-in `=` to which that restriction applies?

Or is that `=` not the bult-in and so that restriction does not apply but the code is flawed for other reasons?

Comment: You are proposing to match `Foo& Foo::operator=(const Foo&)` correct?  A copy assignment operator which is not built-in, but defaulted by the compiler.

Comment: "*instead of being equivalent to this?*" I don't understand why it would be considered. There is nothing to "forbid" it; it simply is not considered as a possibility.

Comment: If you want to be able to do `b = f;` you could add a `Bar(Foo const& foo) : f{foo} {}` constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Paragraph 3 there describes the candidate set:

> - For a unary operator @ with an operand of type cv1 T1, and for a binary operator @ with a left operand of type cv1 T1 and a right operand of type cv2 T2, four sets of candidate functions, designated member candidates, non-member candidates, built-in candidates, and rewritten candidates, are constructed as follows:
>
>   1. If `T1` is a complete class type or a class currently being defined, the set of member candidates is the result of a search for `operator@` in the scope of `T1`; otherwise, the set of member candidates is empty.
>   2. For the operators `=`, `[]`, or `->`, the set of non-member candidates is empty; otherwise [...]

So for `b = f`, our member candidates are `b.operator=(f)` and we have no non-member candidates.

The paragraph that you cited talks about when the built-in candidates are viable, but built-in are those provided by the language (in [[over.built]](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.built)) - those could apply if your type is convertible to something like `int&`. Those aren't relevant here.

But in this case, `b` is convertible to `Foo&`, and there's no mechanism here to consider `Foo::operator=` as a candidate. We only have the member candidates to consider, and only our own (`Bar`'s) members - not arbitrary other types' members.

Answer (score 2):

The copy assignment operator you are considering is not a "built in" operator, but conversion of operands to overloaded operators are also restricted, as follows:

> when converting to the implicit object parameter or when converting to the left operand of an assignment operation only standard conversion sequences are allowed.

https://eel.is/c++draft/over.best.ics#general-9

which is also mentioned in this note

> Note 1: Because only standard conversion sequences are considered when converting to the left operand of an assignment operation ([over.best.ics]), an expression `x = y` with a subexpression `x` of class type is always interpreted as `x.operator=(y)`.

https://eel.is/c++draft/over.oper#over.ass-note-1